# Gorilla Session not setting cookie

Tags: go, gorilla

here is the code for my go server, I have no idea why my gorilla session isn't working. it seems like everything works up to session.save(r, w). I already checked my cookies using the chrome dev tools and no matter what I do I can't get a cookie to appear. I know that my authentication is bad already I just need help with getting sessions working which is my goal. I don't know why this function isn't working can anybody help?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("super-secret"))

func loginAuthHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    username := r.FormValue("username")
    password := r.FormValue("password")
    fmt.Println("username:", username, "password:", password)

    if password == "welcome" && username == "guest" {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "You logged in Succesfully!")

        session, _ := store.Get(r, "session")
        session.Values["authenticated"] = true
        session.Save(r, w)

        fmt.Println("session started!")
        fmt.Println(session)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Wrong Login!")
    }
}

func secret(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "session")

    fmt.Println(session.Values["authenticated"])

    if auth, ok := session.Values["authenticated"].(bool); !ok || !auth {
        http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "The cake is a lie!")

}

func main() {
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Domain:   "localhost",
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   3600 * 8,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/secret", secret)
    http.HandleFunc("/loginauth", loginAuthHandler)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3002", context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux)))
}
```

Here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Go Web App" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <title>Login Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Login Form </h1>
        <p> user: guest | pass: welcome</p> <br>

        <form action="/loginauth" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"> <br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label> <br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs for [`session.Save`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/sessions#Session.Save)

> Save is a convenience method to save this session. It is the same as calling store.Save(request, response, session). You should call Save **before** writing to the response or returning from the handler.

In your code you are writing to the response (`fmt.Fprintf(w, "You logged in Succesfully!")`) before calling `session.Save`. This means that the response (including the headers that contain cookies) is written before the cookie gets set (so the cookies are not sent to the client).

To fix this just move `fmt.Fprintf(w, "You logged in Succesfully!")` underneath the call to `session.Save`.